# I am facing issue in drag and drop in html5 with selenium java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am newbie to java and selenium. i am facing issue in `dragAndDrop` in HTML5. can you please help me?

Code i am using is :

```
public static void draganddrop(WebDriver driver ,WebElement Source, WebElement Destination) 
  {

  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.dragAndDrop(Source, Destination).build().perform();

  }
```

```html
<li data-ng-repeat="item in questionType" id="divDrag0" class="ng-scope"> 
<!-- ngIf: !isSurveyStarted || (isSurveyStarted && !isSurveyLock) -->
  <a data-ng-if="!isSurveyStarted || (isSurveyStarted &amp;&amp; !isSurveyLock)" href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="true" id="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Single Choice </a>
<!-- end ngIf: !isSurveyStarted || (isSurveyStarted && !isSurveyLock) --> 
<!-- ngIf: isSurveyStarted && isSurveyLock --> </li>
```

Comment: No, we cannot help you unless you show your code and state clearly what specific problem you are facing.

Comment: i tried it with simple drag and drop in webdriver, its selecting the source but not dropping to the target

Comment: Hey you can use Action class

Comment: i tried it but not working -   public static void draganddrop(WebDriver driver ,WebElement Source, WebElement Destination) 
  {
  
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.dragAndDrop(Source, Destination).build().perform();

Comment: Relevant HTML please

Comment: Draggable HTML - <li data-ng-repeat="item in questionType" id="divDrag0" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngIf: !isSurveyStarted || (isSurveyStarted && !isSurveyLock) --><a data-ng-if="!isSurveyStarted || (isSurveyStarted &amp;&amp; !isSurveyLock)" href="javascript:void(0)" draggable="true" id="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Single Choice </a><!-- end ngIf: !isSurveyStarted || (isSurveyStarted && !isSurveyLock) -->
<!-- ngIf: isSurveyStarted && isSurveyLock -->
</li>

Answer (score 3):

Try my version of `drag and drop` via `Actions` interface

```
new Actions(driver)
    .moveToElement(source)
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .clickAndHold(source)
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .moveByOffset(1, 0)
    .moveToElement(destination)
    .moveByOffset(1, 0)
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .release().perform();
```

In my application, When I `clickAndHold` the destination element changes. That's why I added pauses.

Comment: @vaishali Does it do anything? Moves mouse to element? Clicks and holds but does not release? More information please :)

Comment: it clicked on the draggable element but not dropping to the location

Answer (score 2):

This is an old problem not fixed yet with Selenium and Html5; but there is a solution that you can find here (credit to rcorreia):
https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544#file-drag_and_drop_helper-js

Just execute that js file `js.ExecuteScript(jsfile + "$('#[sourceElement]').simulateDragDrop({dropTarget: '#[targetElement]'})");`