# Selenium webdriver - drag and drop on Angular/Material design website

Tags: java, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, angular-material

I am trying to automate drag and drop event using selenium java webdriver, against website created with Angular/Material design, I have tried countless of ways, but every single one fail, there are no errors, but nothing gets dragged and dropped.

Here is my sample code:

Website used for test is:

https://smnbbrv.github.io/angular-sortablejs-demo/multiple-lists

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Playground
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://smnbbrv.github.io/angular-sortablejs-demo/multiple-lists");

        WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-multiple-lists/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]"));
        WebElement dropable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-multiple-lists/div[1]/div[2]"));

        // DRAW BORDERS AROUND TO MAKE SURE WE SELECT CORRECT OBJECTS
        drawBorder(driver, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-multiple-lists/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]");
        drawBorder(driver, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-multiple-lists/div[1]/div[2]");

        // TRY USING SELENIUMS ACTION CLASS
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.clickAndHold(draggable).moveToElement(dropable).release().build().perform();

        // TRY AGAIN USING JAVA SCRIPT 
        dragAndDrop(driver, draggable, dropable);
    }

    public static void drawBorder(WebDriver driver, String xpath)
    {
        WebElement element_node = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element_node);
    }

    public static void dragAndDrop(WebDriver driver, WebElement from, WebElement to)
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" + "var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n"
                + "event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" + "event.dataTransfer = {\n" + "data: {},\n"
                + "setData: function (key, value) {\n" + "this.data[key] = value;\n" + "},\n"
                + "getData: function (key) {\n" + "return this.data[key];\n" + "}\n" + "};\n" + "return event;\n"
                + "}\n" + "\n" + "function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n"
                + "if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" + "event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" + "}\n"
                + "if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n"
                + "} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" + "element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" + "}\n"
                + "}\n" + "\n" + "function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n"
                + "var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" + "dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"
                + "var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n"
                + "dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n"
                + "var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n"
                + "dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" + "}\n" + "\n"
                + "var source = arguments[0];\n" + "var destination = arguments[1];\n"
                + "simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", from, to);
    }
}
```

As you can see I used two options, first using Selenium`s Actions class, and second executing JavaScript to perform drag and drop, but nothing works.

Is there any solution to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here have an 'hard' but possible workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49089682/10413416

If this even don't help, worst case scenario is Sikuli

> https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli-api/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/sikuli/api/examples/experimental/DragDropExample.java

*Note: it interacts with the window of browser.*

Comment: Hi @SiKing, as you can see i have provided external link not just to copy paste the code in most cases is handled as "best answer" or stuff like this. In addition there is an extra solution. How marking it as "duplicate" will solve his issues? Thanks